# Passing arguments to 'open' command in MACOS

Tags: c#, shell, .net-core, executable

I have an application in .NET Core and I have to run it using script.
First I thought that I have to have virtual Windows to open few instanses of my application. I had bat scripts with that command:

```
start ./Host/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/win-x64/Host.exe "./CONFIG/host1.json"
```

And now I found that I can create OSX Executable files using command:

```
dotnet publish -r osx-x64 -c Release
```

So now I can use Macos Terminal to start application

```
open ./Host/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/osx-x64/Host --args "./CONFIG/host1.json"
```

BUT I have to pass an argument to Main application and open command doesn't want to pass by my string.

I've tried with `open -a Terminal ...` or `... --args './CONFIG/host1.json'`.

My Host application is opened but args[0] in main is empty.

How can I pass properly my string argument?

Comment: Learn to publish a single file https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file#publish-a-single-file-app---cli and then much easier to run it by `./executable ./CONFIG/hosts1.json`.

Comment: But your Method works in one Terminal window and I have to open several applications (~10 Terminal windows). I have bash script and I want to use sh. Run.sh and then I want to have several Terminals opened.